# How to merge array with same end time with next array start time

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to combine the array into one array if the end time of first array and start time of second array are same.

```
[2019-10-07] => Array
    (


        [0] => Array
            (
                [start_time] => 09:00:00
                [end_time] => 12:00:00
                [working_id] => 55
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [start_time] => 12:00:00
                [end_time] => 13:00:00
                [working_id] => 58
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [start_time] => 13:00:00
                [end_time] => 18:00:00
                [working_id] => 56
            )

    )
```

Output:-

```
[2019-10-07] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 09:00:00
                    [end_time] => 18:00:00
                )
)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this yourself yet?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a working code that produce your included output. If not include you attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `foreach` loop and for each loop you can use `array_column` to get all values of a start_time and end_time. Then you can use max and min function to get the max and min value respectively.

```
$data = array(
    '2019-10-07' => 
    array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'start_time' => '09:00:00',
                    'end_time' => '12:00:00',
                    'working_id' => 55,
                ),

            '1' => array
                (
                    'start_time' => '12:00:00',
                    'end_time' => '13:00:00',
                    'working_id' => 58,
                ),

            '2' => array
                (
                    'start_time' => '13:00:00',
                    'end_time' => '18:00:00',
                    'working_id' => 56,
                ),

        ),
);

$format = array();
foreach( $data as $key => $a ) {
    $format[$key][0] = array();
    $startTimes = array_column( $a, 'start_time');    //get all values with key start_time
    $endTimes = array_column( $a, 'end_time');        //get all values with key end_time
    $format[$key][0]['start_time'] = min( $startTimes );    //get minimum value
    $format[$key][0]['end_time'] = max( $endTimes );        //get maximum value

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($format);
```

Here is the [Demo](https://3v4l.org/HGfFC).

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your comment.

It would give us minumum

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your comment.
It has something missing.

Comment: It would give us minimum and maximum value . it would work if  the end time of the first array same as the start time of second array. it will be failed if the array like this.

Comment: $data=Array
(
    [2019-10-14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 09:00:00
                    [end_time] => 12:00:00
                    [working_id] => 55
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 13:00:00
                    [end_time] => 16:00:00
                    [working_id] => 59
                )
        )
)
Output should be: Same a data